Azure Function cannot access AzureWebJobStorage via private endpoints
tl;dr:  Queue-triggered Azure function trying to access blob storage for Azure-WebJob-Secrets and is denied permission.  There's no such container.  Should I have to create it, and why is it needed, if I'm not accessing blob storage in this storage account, and all secrets needed are in a key vault?
N.B. I found an answer while writing this all out before even posting, and I've added it to the end.  I'm still posting it because I couldn't find this answer searching and it might help others. So scroll to the bottom before you spend a lot of time analyzing to help.... or treat it like an exercise, and see if you can reach the same conclusion I did.

I have an enterprise app that runs its UI, several APIs, and now, an Azure Function (with two more coming), in a P2V3 app service plan.  All are deployed via Terraform and Azure Pipelines.  All are provisioned behind private endpoints.
There is a shared key vault containing secrets, and an application storage account used to store enterprise documents.  All apps in the ASP run as a User Assigned managed identity, and that managed identity is granted GET privileges on secrets in the key vault, and proper privileges to fetch and store to the appropriate containers in the storage account.   The key vault, the storage accounts (blob containers), the database, etc, are all also behind private endpoints.  They all communicate wonderfully through carefully crafted firewall rules and NSGs.
Per guidance from MS (can't recall from where), I've Terraformed a dedicated storage account for each Azure Function.  The new Azure function is triggered by a Queue, so the dedicated storage account contains a queue, and a properly configured private endpoint for that queue.
The .NET 6.0 Function is triggered thusly:
[FunctionName("Process")] 
public void Run
(
    [QueueTrigger("my-queue", Connection = "DedicatedStorageAccountConnection")] string queueItem
)

When the deployed function app starts up, it is unable to access Blob Storage.  The log is nothing but this repeated ad nauseam:
2024-10-30 16:13:01.1540 INFO Request [{GUID}] GET https://{mydedicatedstorage}.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-secrets?restype=container
x-ms-version:2023-11-03
Accept:application/xml
x-ms-client-request-id:{GUID}
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.19.1 (.NET 6.0.32; Microsoft Windows 10.0.20348)
x-ms-date:Wed, 30 Oct 2024 16:13:01 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
2024-10-30 16:13:01.1767 WARN Error response [{GUID}] 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation. (00.0s)
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:{GUID}
x-ms-client-request-id:{GUID}
x-ms-error-code:AuthorizationFailure
Date:Wed, 30 Oct 2024 16:13:00 GMT
Content-Length:246
Content-Type:application/xml


I'm not sure why it's trying to get something out of a blob container called "azure-webjob-secrets", as that container doesn't exist.  (The Terraform module only creates blob storage, queues and tables as required for the Azure function in question.)
I will try to provide as much info below as possible, both from Terraform, and from Azure Portal.
This is the TF module that is re-used by the new Azure Function (and the two coming after).
Comments are added for this post for context:
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "function_app_dedicated_storage_connection_string" {
  key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id
  name         = "${var.function_name_short}-function-app-dedicated-storage-connection-string"
  value        = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.primary_connection_string
  content_type = "Connection String"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      content_type,
      tags
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "function_app_dedicated_storage_account" {
  name                             = var.dedicated_storage_account_name
  resource_group_name              = var.resource_group_name
  location                         = var.location
  account_tier                     = var.sa_tier
  account_replication_type         = var.sa_replication_type
  access_tier                      = var.sa_access_tier
  account_kind                     = var.sa_kind
  tags                             = var.tags
  min_tls_version                  = "TLS1_2"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public  = false
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false

  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    bypass = [
      "AzureServices",
      "Logging",
      "Metrics"
    ]

    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
      var.hub_admin_subnet_id,
      var.hub_azdo_subnet_id
    ]

    ip_rules = var.general_ip_whitelist
  }
  
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [
      var.user_assigned_managed_identity_id
    ]
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}

# Designed to be flexible, you can pass in 0 to multiple tables needed by the function, and
# the count parameter will control whether, or how many, tables will be created. The 
# function in question passes in a single table.

resource "azurerm_storage_table" "function_app_table" {
  for_each             = var.storage_tables
  name                 = each.value
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.name
}

# Ditto here.  The primary use in the problem app is a queue trigger.  I pass a 
# single queue name for this when calling the module.

resource "azurerm_storage_queue" "function_app_queue" {
  for_each             = var.storage_queues
  name                 = each.value
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.name
}

# No containers will be created here -- I am not passing in any container names

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "function_app_blob_container" {
  for_each             = var.blob_containers
  name                 = each.value
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.name
}

# No private endpoint will be created for blob storage, since I didn't pass in any container names

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_function_app_blob" {
  count               = length(var.blob_containers) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name                = "pe-storage-blob-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.private_endpoint_resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  tags                = var.tags

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "${var.function_name}-sa-dns-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["${var.private_zone_id}privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "pe-storage-blob-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.function_module.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }
}

# There is a table passed in, so a private endpoint for "table" subresources will be created here

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_function_app_table" {
  count               = length(var.storage_tables) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name                = "pe-storage-table-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.private_endpoint_resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  tags                = var.tags

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "${var.function_name}-sa-dns-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["${var.private_zone_id}privatelink.table.core.windows.net"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "pe-storage-table-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["table"]
  }
}

# There is a queue name passed in, so a private endpoint for queue subresources will be created here

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_function_app_queue" {
  count               = length(var.storage_queues) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name                = "pe-storage-queue-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.private_endpoint_resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  tags                = var.tags

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "${var.function_name}-sa-dns-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["${var.private_zone_id}privatelink.queue.core.windows.net"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "pe-storage-queue-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["queue"]
  }
}

# This is the private endpoint for the function app itself, in the "sites" subresource

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_function_app" {
  name                = "pe-function-app-${var.function_name_short}-${var.instance_resource_prefix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  tags                = var.tags

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "${var.function_name}_app_dns_group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["${var.private_zone_id}privatelink.azurewebsites.net"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "pe-function-app-${var.function_name_short}-${var.instance_resource_prefix}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.function_module.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["sites"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "function_to_vnet" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.function_module.id
  subnet_id      = var.app_subnet_outbound_id

  timeouts {
    create = "5m"
  }
}

# Finally, the actual function app, with the params as passed in.

resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function_module" {
  name                            = var.function_name
  location                        = var.location
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id                 = var.app_service_plan_id
  tags                            = var.tags
  key_vault_reference_identity_id = var.user_assigned_managed_identity_id
  app_settings                    = local.merged_app_settings

  storage_account_name            = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.name
  storage_account_access_key      = azurerm_storage_account.function_app_dedicated_storage_account.primary_access_key

  https_only = true
  public_network_access_enabled = false

  site_config {
    always_on                 = true
    app_command_line          = null
    ftps_state                = "FtpsOnly"
    health_check_path         = null
    http2_enabled             = true
    managed_pipeline_mode     = "Integrated"
    remote_debugging_enabled  = false
    vnet_route_all_enabled    = true
    use_32_bit_worker         = false

    application_stack {
      use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = false
      dotnet_version = var.dotnet_version
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
      tags,
      virtual_network_subnet_id,
      app_settings["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"],
      app_settings["WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE"],
      app_settings["STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"],
      site_config["elastic_instance_minimum"],
      site_config["remote_debugging_version"],
      site_config["scm_type"]
    ]
  }

  dynamic "connection_string" {
    for_each = var.connection_strings
    content {
      name  = connection_string.key
      type  = connection_string.value["type"]
      value = connection_string.value["value"]
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [
      var.user_assigned_managed_identity_id
    ]
  }
}


And here's the TF code that calls that module to create the specific function in question (with some config redactions):
module "target_function" {
  source                               = "./azure_function"
  function_name                        = local.app_target_func       
  function_name_short                  = "target"
  dedicated_storage_account_name       = local.target_function_app_sa_name

# Note the absence of any storage_containers, thus none will be created

  storage_queues                       = ["create-queue"]
  storage_tables                       = ["createAuditTable"]
  resource_group_name                  = azurerm_resource_group.app_rg.name 
  resource_group_name_data             = data.azurerm_resource_group.data_rg.name
  location                             = var.location                       
  tags                                 = local.tags
  sa_kind                              = var.sa_kind
  sa_tier                              = var.sa_tier
  sa_replication_type                  = var.sa_replication_type
  sa_access_tier                       = var.sa_access_tier
  tenant_id                            = var.tenant_id
  key_vault_id                         = azurerm_key_vault.instance_kv.id
  hub_admin_subnet_id                  = var.hub_admin_subnet_id
  hub_azdo_subnet_id                   = var.hub_azdo_subnet_id
  app_service_plan_id                  = azurerm_service_plan.trade_app_plan.id
  private_endpoint_subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.private_endpoint_subnet.id
  app_subnet_inbound_id                = data.azurerm_subnet.app_subnet_inbound.id
  app_subnet_outbound_id               = data.azurerm_subnet.app_subnet_outbound.id
  private_zone_id                      = local.private_zone_id
  instance_resource_prefix             = local.instance_resource_prefix
  user_assigned_managed_identity_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.app_service_ident.id
  private_endpoint_resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.pe_rg.name
  general_ip_whitelist                 = var.general_ip_whitelist_onpremise_firewall

  app_settings = {
    "ApplicationName"                         = "TargetingFunction"
    "InstanceKeyVault"                        = "${azurerm_key_vault.instance_kv.vault_uri}"
    "SpokeKeyVault"                           = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.spoke_kv.vault_uri}"
    "InstanceStorageAccountConnectionString"  = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${azurerm_key_vault_secret.AzureConfiguration_ConnectionString.versionless_id})"

    # The @KV= nomenclature is an internal function to get secrets from the key vault 
    # without having to use Microsoft.KeyVault().  This avoids having a circular
    # dependency in the module (I don't have to reference the resource created in the
    # module, here outside the module) and allows the connection string to remain secret

    "DedicatedStorageAccountConnectionString" = "@KV=instance/create-function-app-dedicated-storage-connection-string"
  }

  connection_strings = {
    "MasterConnection" = { "type" = "SQLAzure", "value" = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${azurerm_key_vault_secret.ui_master_db_conn_string.versionless_id})" }
  }
}


Nowhere in the above do I reference a setting anything close to "WebJobs", but it seems to be closely related to the Queue trigger, because if I comment out the "using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" statement in the .cs file, the [QueueTrigger] and [FunctionName]  attributes go out of scope.
Things do work when I run locally, because my local.settings.json uses Development storage:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    ....

Finally, before I modularized the Terraform to be re-usable, I was still using dedicated storage accounts, and even then I was not creating the webjobs containers manually.... but they are there, in other environments to which the modularized Terraform has not been applied.  But I have no idea where these came from (this is an older environment):

But in the new environment, as deployed by the above Terraform:

So, how do I get this to run when deployed to Azure?   Do I manually create the azure-webjob-secrets blob container (which would thus trigger my Terraform module to create the private endpoint for blob storage, said endpoints being required by InfoSec posture)?  Why were they seemingly created before, automatically, but not now?
A quick look at the pre-modularized Terraform shows that the blob storage private endpoint was previously created automatically, even though no containers were created.  It was at the time of modularization that the module was made to accept an arbitrary number of blob containers, queues, and tables, since each function might have different needs.  I was trying to make it as reusable as possible.
I now suspect that in putting the blob storage private endpoint behind a "count" clause and then not creating a container, I sabotaged previously working code.

Pre-modularization private endpoint creation:

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_create_func_sa_blob" {
  name                = "create_func_sa_endpoint_blob_${local.instance_resource_prefix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.pe_rg.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.private_endpoint_subnet.id
  tags                = local.tags

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "${local.app_name}_sa_dns_group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["${local.private_zone_id}privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "create-func-sa-endpoint-blob-${local.instance_resource_prefix}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.create_function_app_storage_account.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }
}

# TODO Modularize the above (first function app) and below (second and third ones) so we're not having to copy/pasta and use hardcoded resource names.



Aaaaand, bingo, that was it. Once I took the "count" out of the private endpoint creation for blob storage, it magically started working.
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_function_app_blob" {
  # Blob private endpoint must be created for azure-webjobs-secrets and azure-webjobs-hosts containers, even if no 
  # container is created by parameter; thus, unlike tables and queues, this resource doesn't have or need a "count"
  name                = "pe-storage-blob-${var.function_name_short}-func-${var.instance_resource_prefix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.private_endpoint_resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  tags                = var.tags
  ...

And once the above was applied, the new logs show a successful initial GET, plus successful subsequent HEAD and PUT calls to the azure-webjobs-hosts container (not shown).  Note the new URL on the GET that is locating the host.json file, which wasn't there before:
2024-10-30 18:38:44.9083 INFO Request [{GUID}] GET https://{mydedicatedstorage}.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-secrets/create-func/host.json
x-ms-version:2023-11-03
Accept:application/xml
x-ms-client-request-id:{GUID}
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.19.1 (.NET 6.0.32; Microsoft Windows 10.0.20348)
x-ms-date:Wed, 30 Oct 2024 18:38:44 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
2024-10-30 18:38:44.9591 INFO Response [{GUID}] 200 OK (00.0s)
Accept-Ranges:bytes
ETag:"REDACTED"
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:{GUID}
x-ms-client-request-id:{GUID}
x-ms-version:2023-11-03
x-ms-creation-time:Wed, 30 Oct 2024 18:36:06 GMT
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-lease-state:available
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted:true
Date:Wed, 30 Oct 2024 18:38:43 GMT
Content-Length:1172
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Content-MD5:REDACTED
Last-Modified:Wed, 30 Oct 2024 18:36:08 GMT


2024-10-30 18:38:45.0334 INFO Request [4a4a678e-32fa-482b-94fa-7b6fb5411b11] HEAD https://{mydedicatedstorage}.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts/synctriggers/create-func/last
2024-10-30 18:38:45.0806 INFO Response [4a4a678e-32fa-482b-94fa-7b6fb5411b11] 404 The specified blob does not exist. (00.0s)


2024-10-30 18:38:45.5589 INFO Request [6189e319-dfc1-420a-b9c8-3593f37adcc9] PUT https://{mydedicatedstorage}.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts/synctriggers/create-func/last
2024-10-30 18:38:45.6106 INFO Response [6189e319-dfc1-420a-b9c8-3593f37adcc9] 201 Created (00.0s)


If you read along with this to this solution, thanks for putting up with the meandering, and I hope this helps someone else thus stymied.
Jeff Woods
Reading, PA

I included the answer in the original post above.  I'll mark this as the answer.
